# Linux: Configure external PFC8523 RTC

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, i2c, device-tree

I have a custom board with a SAMA5D2 and an external PFC8523 RTC. After modifying the DTS (device tree) I managed to get the RTC working.

The problem I'm facing is that pin 7 of the RTC (named `INT1/CLKOUT`) is by default configured to be a clock output whereas I'd like to use it as an interrupt/alarm output. For this, I need to change some bits in the RTC's control registers.

I attempted to do this via `i2cset` from userspace. However, that is not possible as the driver claims the I2C device.

What is the correct way of changing an RTC's configuration register?
I assume that this is not possible from the DTS (device tree).

Comment: The "*correct way*" IMO would involve defining a DT property for the configuration of this device's pin. Then add code to the Linux driver to use this new DT property to configure the device during probe/initialization. Use the driver's existing `quartz-load-femtofarads` property as an example. A hacker's way would skip the DT property, and just hardcode their required configuration into the driver's probe/initialization.

Comment: Isn't it already supported by the driver https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.4-rc1/source/drivers/rtc/rtc-pcf8523.c#L452? You have just to add an interrupt to your tree and maybe mark it as `wakeup-source`.